# How to make list of words that are not in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, twitter, data-preprocessing

I have a problem with python pandas dataframe problem. I have two dataframes with different contents. I want to output words that are not in dataframe 2 and store them on a new dataframe. Can someone help me in solving this problem using python pandas dataframe? Thankyouu...

Where dataframe 1 contains:

Tweet

Bismillah for tomorrow Amin

shared location

Replying to shahrilPng

It's time to finish what's been pending

up and parallel

When you run after your dream

And dataframe 2 contains:

Words

tomorrow

shared

location

time

finish

pending

parallel

run

after

dream

The output that i want

Results

Bismillah

for

Amin

Replying

to

shahrilPng

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split and explode your `tweets` dataframe and check if each words is present in your `words` dataframe:

```
# check function
not_in_list = lambda x: ~x.str.casefold().isin(df2['Words'].str.casefold())

out = df1['Tweet'].str.split().explode().loc[not_in_list] \
                  .drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('Results')
print(out)

# Output
       Results
0    Bismillah
1          for
2         Amin
3     Replying
4           to
5   shahrilPng
6         It's
7       what's
8         been
9           up
10         and
11        When
12         you
13        your
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to turn the dataframes to a flatten set, find the differences and put them into a dtaframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1_set = set(np.ravel(df1.values))
df2_set = set(np.ravel(df2.values))
pd.DataFrame(df1_set - df2_set).dropna()
```